# How can I link to a script in a different file?

Tags: html

```
Folder1
   Item1
Folder2
   Item2
```

How can I link Item 2 to item 1. I have tried `"/Folder2/Item.extension"` that didn't work. And I've tried without the `/` at the beginning.

Comment: are these also both in a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Using relative paths, try:

```
"../Folder2/Item2"
```

The double dot notation means the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute paths, assuming Folder1 is at the root of your project, try:

```
"/Folder2/Item2"
```

This way, if you move the file, you won't have to worry about changing the path.